# recyclerview No adapter attached

Tags: java, android, json, android-recyclerview

I try to download JSON but when I launch app I get this.

```
recyclerview No adapter attached
```

Here is code of my Main Activity

```
 package com.example.nemes.myapplication;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.View;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
    // CONNECTION_TIMEOUT and READ_TIMEOUT are in milliseconds
    public static final int CONNECTION_TIMEOUT = 10000;
    public static final int READ_TIMEOUT = 15000;
    private RecyclerView StreamComponent;
    private Adapter mAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);

        new AsyncFetch().execute();
    }
    private class AsyncFetch extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
        ProgressDialog pdLoading = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        HttpURLConnection conn;
        URL url = null;

      /*  @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

            //this method will be running on UI thread
            pdLoading.setMessage("\tLoading...");
            pdLoading.setCancelable(false);
            pdLoading.show();

        }*/

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            try {

                // Enter URL address where your json file resides
                // Even you can make call to php file which returns json data
                url = new URL(" http://api.learn2crack.com/android/jsonandroid");

            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
                return e.toString();
            }
            try {

                // Setup HttpURLConnection class to send and receive data from php and mysql
                conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                conn.setReadTimeout(READ_TIMEOUT);
                conn.setConnectTimeout(CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
                conn.setRequestMethod("GET");

                // setDoOutput to true as we recieve data from json file
                conn.setDoOutput(true);

            } catch (IOException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
                return e1.toString();
            }

            try {

                int response_code = conn.getResponseCode();

                // Check if successful connection made
                if (response_code == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {

                    // Read data sent from server
                    InputStream input = conn.getInputStream();
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input));
                    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
                    String line;

                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        result.append(line);
                    }

                    // Pass data to onPostExecute method
                    return (result.toString());

                } else {

                    return ("unsuccessful");
                }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return e.toString();
            } finally {
                conn.disconnect();
            }


        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

            //this method will be running on UI thread

            pdLoading.dismiss();
            List<Data> data = new ArrayList<>();

            pdLoading.dismiss();
            try {


                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);
                JSONArray jArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("android");
                // Extract data from json and store into ArrayList as class objects
                for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    Data StreamData = new Data();
                    //fishData.fishImage= json_data.getString("fish_img");
                    StreamData.Name = json_data.getString("name");
                    // fishData.catName= json_data.getString("cat_name");
                    // fishData.sizeName= json_data.getString("size_name");
                    //fishData.price= json_data.getInt("price");
                    data.add(StreamData);
                }

                // Setup and Handover data to recyclerview
                StreamComponent = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.StreamList);
                mAdapter = new Adapter(MainActivity.this, data);
                StreamComponent.setAdapter(mAdapter);
                StreamComponent.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this));

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }

    }
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
            // Handle the camera action
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {



        } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

        }


        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
}
```

I think  this causes by this row  `new AsyncFetch().execute();` because when I comment it, app launches well.

Where I need to place it for well working app?

**UPDATE**

Error was in permission. Sorry for disinformation.

Now I have another error. App launches and I don't see recycle view.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z2wVE.png)

Comment: @Eugena, Yes error is coming because you have commented out new AsyncFetch().execute(); thing. Can you explain what was issue when uncomment this line ?

Comment: Nope. When I uncomment it, I have error.

When it commented, app is launching @dex

Comment: I guess you see `recyclerview No adapter attached` in logcat. It's not an error, it's just means that you haven't set adapter in onCreate, so RecyclerView won't show anything initially. You will set adapter later from async task, but it might be some problem there that fails to set it properly. What I'm trying to say is that `recyclerview No adapter attached` has nothing to do with your problem.

Comment: @Eugene "When I uncomment it, I have error" can you paste that error via adb logcat?

Comment: Okay. Sorry. My app crashes because I try to download data and don't set permission.

I set permission and app launches.


But I have error. I will update post now @Gudin

Comment: I updated post@Gudin

Comment: I updated post@dex

Comment: @Eugene make sure your adapter have data which will be visible to users and it will easy to debug if you copy paste your adapter class also

Comment: You should set up few breakpoints and debug your AsyncTask, because there are lot of stuff that might be a problem. Your download might fail, data migh, it might be empty or something might be wrong in adapter (like returning 0 for view count). You gave us no clues on your problem.

Comment: Look I have Test app with only recyclerview. It works and shows data.

I paste code with DrawerLayout and now I don't see any data@dex